# "/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected" in crontab's outputs

Tags: linux, bash, cron

In crontab I have this job script :

```
0 5 * * * /home/user/job_h.bash > /home/user/log_h.log > 2&1
```

where the job_h.bash contains :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e
source /home/user/pyenv/test/bin/activate
python3 /home/user/pyenv/test/d_h.py
deactivate
```

However it outputs `"/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected"`

Would you please help me to understand ? I'm pretty sure that i'm using the right shebang and finally the python isn't executed ‍♀️

Thank you,

Comment: (1) "it outputs" – Where to? To `/home/user/log_h.log`? To the e-mail cron sends to you? (2) What do you mean by `> 2&1`? Do you want `2>&1`?

Comment: (1) it's to send logs through mail and to save into the file ```/home/user/log_h.log```
(2) I meant to save and send only errors

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is the `> 2&1`, but from your description I'm not sure what it should be. `> /home/user/log_h.log 2>&1` would send both standard output *and* errors to the log_h.log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  almost certain your redirection for stderr is wrong. (the last 3 characters) Try

```
  home/user/job_h.bash > /home/user/log_h.log 2>&1
```

The problem is your command, as written is trying to redirect stdout twice.